Button to add an alert in Apache Superset is disabled even after filling all fields
I am using Python 3.10.12 and have run pip install apache-superset to install superset.
I've added the feature of alert in superset_config.py
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
'ALERT_REPORTS': True,
}

But when adding an alert through the form the add button is disabled stating that the email recipients field is not filled even though it is:

How do I fix this?

GitHub issue for this.
